# Pandas Multiindex row of data edit/access

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem I cannot find solution to.

I have Multiindex array, one index is timestamp, the second one is string, columns are strings too.

see here

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np


houses = ['house01', 'house02']             # index 1
date_from = pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1, 1)     # index 2
hours = np.array([date_from + datetime.timedelta(hours = i) for i in range(5)])
columnsx = ['electricity', 'gas', 'heat']   # columns

# multiindex preparation
house_array = []
hours_array = []
for hour in hours:
    hours_array += list(hours)
for house in houses:
    house_array += [house]*len(hours)

arrays = [
    hours_array,
    house_array
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['hour', 'item'])

# Dataframe with zeros (values should be filled then column by column)
house_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(block_id)*len(hours),(len(columnsx)))), index = indices, columns = columnsx)
print(house_dataframe)

# i need to edit columns or rows of the dataframe, e.g.:
electricity_data_house_1 = [100, 200, 150, 130, 200]
house_dataframe[:,houses[0],columns[0]] = electricity_data_house_1
```

Comment: Can you please add some more information, such as current data frame and expected output

Comment: The created dataframe is full of zeros and I want to edit it column by column, (eg. one column is vector of electricity consumption in house 1 for, one element for one timestamp). Then I want to read the data column by column for further processing such as MS Excel reporting etc.

Comment: Hi @roubalikm, I am learning along with your questions, there are some typo in your codes. I gave a try below, let me know if it helps you on your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IndexSlice

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

house_dataframe.loc[idx[:, houses[0]], columnsx[0]] = electricity_data_house_1
```

Output

```
                             electricity  gas  heat
hour                item                           
2021-01-01 01:00:00 house01        100.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 02:00:00 house01        200.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 03:00:00 house01        150.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 04:00:00 house01        130.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 05:00:00 house01        200.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 01:00:00 house02          0.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 02:00:00 house02          0.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 03:00:00 house02          0.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 04:00:00 house02          0.0  0.0   0.0
2021-01-01 05:00:00 house02          0.0  0.0   0.0
```

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np


houses = ["house01", "house02"]  # index 1
date_from = pd.Timestamp(2021, 1, 1, 1)  # index 2
hours = np.array([date_from + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(5)])
columnsx = ["electricity", "gas", "heat"]  # columns

# multiindex preparation
house_array = []
hours_array = []
for hour in hours:
    hours_array += list(hours)
for house in houses:
    house_array += [house] * len(hours)

arrays = [hours_array, house_array]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["hour", "item"])

# Dataframe with zeros (values should be filled then column by column)
house_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    np.zeros((len(houses) * len(hours), (len(columnsx)))),
    index=indices,
    columns=columnsx,
)

# i need to edit columns or rows of the dataframe, e.g.:
electricity_data_house_1 = [100, 200, 150, 130, 200]

idx = pd.IndexSlice
house_dataframe.loc[idx[:, houses[0]], columnsx[0]] = electricity_data_house_1
print(house_dataframe)
```

Comment: Hey, Lejen! that's perfect solution, thank you a lot! :-)

Comment: @roubalikm, you are welcome, happy to help